# Restkit sending Get request instead of Post

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails-3, restkit

I'm just starting to use Restkit and am trying to send a regular POST request "serverUrl/account/authenticate.xml?OPTIONS" to get a response as XML. This is the code I use to call the URL:

```
 -(void) function{

    // OBJECT MANAGER
    RKObjectManager* manager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:serverUrl];
    [manager.router routeClass:[CBUser class] toResourcePath:@"/account/authenticate" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];


    // OBJECT MAPPING
    RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CBUser class]];
    mapping = [manager.mappingProvider objectMappingForKeyPath:@"user"];
    [mapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"userId"];

    [manager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:str objectMapping:mapping delegate:self];
}


// DELEGATE
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray*)objects {  
    CBUser* user = [objects objectAtIndex:0];  
    NSLog(@"Loaded Contact ID #%@ -> Firstname: %@, Lastname: %@", user.userId, user.firstname, user.lastname);  
}  

- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError*)error {  
    NSLog(@"Encountered an error: %@", error); 
}
```

Looking at the server log it seems it receives a GET request instead of a POST even though I'm using the "RKRequestMethodPOST" option.

Here is my error form my logs:

```
Started GET "/account/authenticate.xml?commit=Login&authenticity_token=iPhone&user%5Bpassword=XXXXX&user%5Bemail=XXXXXXX%5D&user%5Bdevice_token=XXXXXXX" for 192.168.106.30 at 2012-01-25 19:20:03 -0800

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'show' could not be found for AccountController):


Rendered /Users/Guillaume/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/unknown_action.erb within rescues/layout (1.2ms)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: it's good form to mark an answer as correct or explain why it didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this code snippet of my app will help. You setup your mappings, say in your delegate. Note the "forMethod"

```
    RKObjectRouter *router;

    RKObjectMapping* createAccountSerializationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Cr    eateAccount class]];
    [createAccountSerializationMapping mapAttributes:@"email", @"pwd", @"uname", nil];

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:createAccountSerializationMapping forClass:[CreateAccount class]];

    router = [RKObjectRouter new] ;
    [router routeClass:[CreateAccount class] toResourcePath:@"/registration/rest/users/create_account" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];

    [RKObjectManager sharedManager].router = router;
```

and then later, when you want to post an object

```
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:user delegate:self];
```